# Abbrev expansion after quotation mark

Tags: auctex, abbrev, markdown-mode

I've looked for a solution to this a number of times. Suppose 'kg' normally expands to 'knowledge' in my abbrev file. I wonder if there is any way to get emacs to expand after a single or double quotation mark, as in expanding from

> `"kg`

to

> `"knowledge`

I don't know lisp well but am willing to play with my .emacs. Thanks for any help!

*Edit*: I just noticed that it works fine in the scratch buffer, but not in markdown or LaTeX modes.

Comment: It's technically a small bug in LaTeX mode, because it redefines the double quote key and so the abbrev doesn't expand. What's your emacs version, I can write you a workaround.

Comment: GNU Emacs 24.3.1 - but it happens in markdown mode too, where the quotation-mark substitution does not take place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
(with-eval-after-load 'tex-mode
 (defun expand-and-insert-space ()
  (interactive)
  (expand-abbrev)
  (insert "\ ")))

(define-key latex-mode-map (kbd "<SPC>") 'expand-and-insert-space)
(define-key latex-mode-map (kbd "<M-/>") 'expand-abbrev)
```

EDITED to include `eval-after-load`

Comment: Hmm thanks! I tried that but got `Symbol's value as variable is void: latex-mode-map`. Unfortunately this means little to me.

Comment: Could be fixed by wrapping in `(with-eval-after-load 'tex-mode ...)`.

Comment: Sorry I only just saw this answer - I guess I don't have notifications on. It seems to work, thanks! To be clear, I just add that first code line, `(with-eval-after-load 'tex-mode (defun expand-and-insert-space () (interactive) (expand-abbrev) (insert "\ ")))` - right?

Comment: You should add the whole thing so that you can remap the space key. This is a hacky workaround and won't expand, for instance, when you hit delimiters like `,` and `.` unless you redefine those also.